# How to dynamically access user-entered Input-field-data, in Javascript or J-Query

Tags: javascript, jquery, user-input

*HELP!!....  I can't dynamically access data entered by users into `Input` fields!*

I'm a curriculum-designer trying to make a 'Matching'-activity  (18-questions-with-18-scrambled-up-possible-answers), in which answer-choices get dynamically crossed out, 1 by 1, as they get 'used up' by the student, whenever (s)he types the letter of that choice (in this case "r") into the input-field.  Here's the HTML for 1 of those 18 matches:  (Hint: Pay attention to  the "id"-attributes)

## HTML

```
<input title="Question 18 - type 'R' into this input field" 
    class="questions" maxlength="1" id="18" onblur="My_Blur_Fx(this);">   
</input>

<span class="r_as_selected, choices" id="r">  <!--I use the first class ('r_as_selected') in the J-Query example below, and the 2nd class ('choices') in the Javascript example below.-->
    [Choice] R. (**All this span should soon be crossed-out.**) 
</span>
```

I thought I could pull this off with a "change" event.  However, neither my Javascript, nor my J-Query seems to be able to do it, because neither one can dynamically access the user's typed-in input (the very stuff that PHP would normally access via GET or POST).

## J-Query

My J-Query-attempt to dynamically access this user-entered input...

```
$("input").change(function(){

    $("input"[value="r"])
        .add('.r_as_selected')
            .eq(1).css({'color': 'red', 'text-decoration': 'line-through'})
});
```

...failed because, although it could cross out the '#r' answer-choice, yet it would ALSO cross it out whenever they typed in ANYTHING....So the `[value='r']` part of the code wasn't able to target *JUST* the field where someone had typed 'r'.

## Javascript

My Javascript-attempt to dynamically access this user-entered input...

```
<script> 
    function My_Blur_Fx(x) {
        var userInput = document.getElementById(x).value;      
        var userChoices = document.getElementsByClassName("choices").id;

        var i;
        for(i = 0; i < 18; i++)
                { if (userChoices[i].attributes[1].value == userInput) {
                        /*Note: "attributes[1] is my way of accessing the 2nd attribute in the HTML span above, which is 'id="r"'*/ 
                    userChoices[i].style.textDecoration = "line-through";};
                };
    }
</script>
```

...failed too because an 'Input' is an "Element" whose "Value," is defined by the DOM to be "NULL,"...so line 3 above gives an error. Neither could any of the other potentially-relevant DOM-modifiers, instead of `.value` (i.e. `.innerHTML` / `.nodeValue` / `.attributes`) access that user-entered value.  So it seems that 'Input' elements just can't be accessed dynamically. . . .   ( Any suggestions...J-Query, Javascript, or other? )

Comment: Aren't you getting a syntax error for `$("input"[value="r"])`? Your code won't run at all because of that.

Comment: I can't figure out what you're trying to do. Are you trying to find the input where the user typed `r`? Or are you trying to test if he typed `r` into the current input that changed?

Comment: If you're dynamically rendering the html (via php) you need to use a delegate event handler. In jQuery, you'd use [`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead of `.click()`

Comment: @Barmar - Yeah, that might be a problem.  I also tried moving the double-quotation mark to wrap the [value] modifier,  `$("input[value=\'r\']")`,   but that doesn't work either:   Any suggestions?  (I'm brand new at J-Query.)

Comment: @wahwahwah - No, I'm not using PHP at all.  (This is all front-end.)  Thanks for the .on() suggestion.  I'll try that.

Comment: @Barmar - I'm trying to find ANY input where the user typed R.

Comment: Are you sure you want `.eq(1)`? That will find the second element in the set, because it's zero-based.

Comment: @Barbar - Yeah, I intentionally used `.eq(1).`  The plan is that I first `.add('.r_as_selected')`, so that I now have a pseudo-2-classes-in-1-mega-class, and then `.eq(1)` Identifies just the 2nd of those 2 classes for cross-out, which happens to be the html-span containing the scrambled-answer-choice which I want crossed-out.

Comment: @Barbar - BTW, I edited that last comment, when I suddenly realized that maybe my 2-in-1 plan isn't working at all, but might be exactly what's wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an attribute selector to match user input, it only matches the static attributes, not the dynamic values. You can use `.filter()` to search for an element that matches a selector and has a specific value.

```
$("input").change(function() {
    $("input").filter(function() {
        return this.value == 'r';
    }).add(".r_as_selected")
        .eq(1).css({'color': 'red', 'text-decoration': 'line-through'});
});
```

You have several problems in `MyBlurFx()`.

1. `document.getElementById(x).value` won't work beceause `x` is the element, not its ID. You should just use `x.value`.
2. `document.getElementsByClassName("choices").id` won't work because `getElementsByClassName()` returns a `NodeList`, not a single element, so it doesn't have an `id` property. But you don't need the ID, just use `document.getElementsByClassName("choices")`, since the `for` loop operates on the elements, not IDs.

Comment: Hmm.  I never thought of also using `.filter()` with `.val()`.  I'll try that.  In the meantime, I'd point out, though, that it seems that you didn't use `.val()`, in your code, here.

Comment: Nice explanation, but there's a syntax error here (extraneous `});`)

Comment: @rudminda `$(this).val()` is the same as `this.value`. No need to make an unnecessary jQuery call there.

Comment: @MattBrowne Yeah, I saw that you edited that as I was making other changes. I fixed it.

Comment: I don't seem to be able to make it work.  It seems as if I'm not allowed to do a javascript **conditional function** inside of a Jquery, e.g.        `$("input").change( function(){     **If(...) {...}** }  ;})`

Comment: Small `i` in `if`.

Comment: If that's not the problem, what was the error you got from that? There's nothing special about jQuery that would prevent using a conditional.

Comment: What???...You can't be serious.  What????.... **SMALL 'i'**?  SMALL I!!!   All that for 1 iota?!!     Thank you,  Barbar.

Comment: So, just for the record, either of these 2 options will ALSO do the trick, in addition to the solution above.  Here, first is **ALTERNATIVE OPTION 1**:   `<script>
$("input").change(function(){

    if ($("input").filter(function(){return this.value == 'r';}).length>0) {$("#r").css({'color': 'red', 'text-decoration': 'line-through'})    ;}
;})
</script>`

Comment: Then next is **ALTERNATIVE OPTION 2*** `<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("input").on("change", function(){

        if ($("input").filter(function(){return this.value == 'r';}).length>0) {$("#r").css({'color': 'red', 'text-decoration': 'line-through'})                         ;}
                                        ;})

                            });

</script>`

Comment: There's no difference between `.on("change"...)` and `.change(...)`

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there is more than one mistake, but I see that your code `$("input"[value="r"])` is same as `$(undefined)`. You must use `$('input[value=\'r\']')` instead.

Comment: Hmm.  I tried that.  It doesn't seem to work, but--you're right--there may be other problems, too.